# 'add to home screen' Web App Install Banner not showing up

Tags: mobile-website, banner, progressive-web-apps

I don't get an 'add to home screen' banner when I go on my website.
My service worker is ok and my manifest.json too

When i try the add to homescreen in chrome dev with my desktop i have the banner but i don't have it automaticaly with my android phone

Can you help me please

Comment: Did you check the [New and Improved Add to Home screen](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen)?

Comment: make sure you meet the [criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria) and that you are serving the files through an ssl secure connection

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do in this situation is to start by opening up *Chrome Dev Tools* on a desktop computer. Navigate to the "**Audits**" tab. The screen should look something like this:

[Chrome Dev Tools Audit Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziL4T.png) (click to view image)

Make sure you have "**Mobile**" checked since this seems to only be an issue with mobile for you, then click "**Run audits**". It should come back with something like this:

[PWA Audit Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or18F.png) (click to view image)

In this example, everything is correct so we see the green circle with "100". If there is anything wrong with how the PWA is implemented, it will be noted here with an error.

Hopefully you find this helpful, along with anyone else who runs into this issue!

Comment: thank's for your replay, I was thinking i will prompt any time i will go on the website but i think it's impossible